# First widget updates second widget

Tags: java, android

If I have two widgets and I press on a button on the first one, the second widget updates itself. That is not the intention :) When debugging I noticed that the first widget the widgetid of te second used for updating

```
public class WidgetActivity extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public static WidgetActivity Widget = null;
    public static Context context;
    public static AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
    public static int appWidgetIds[];   
    public static String ACTION_OPEN_APP = "OpenApp";
    private static int appWidgetId;


    @Override
    public void onUpdate( Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds )    {     
        if (null == context) context = WidgetActivity.context;
        if (null == appWidgetManager) appWidgetManager = WidgetActivity.appWidgetManager;
        if (null == appWidgetIds) appWidgetIds = WidgetActivity.appWidgetIds;

        WidgetActivity.Widget = this;
        WidgetActivity.context = context;
        WidgetActivity.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
        WidgetActivity.appWidgetIds = appWidgetIds;

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
        {
            appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];  

            updateAppWidget(context,appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);            
        }

    }


    public void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int appWidgetId) {

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);

        Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
        configIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent configPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, configIntent, 0);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.headlinesBox, configPendingIntent);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.WidgetRefresh_btn, pendingIntent);

        setHeadlines(appWidgetId);

        // Tell the widget manager
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
    }

    public static void setHeadlines(int appWidgetId)
    {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

        ArrayList<String> newsItems = getRssItems("*****rss.php", appWidgetId); 

        if(newsItems.size() == 3)
        {
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.headline1, newsItems.get(0));
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.headline2, newsItems.get(1));
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.headline3, newsItems.get(2));
        }

        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
        CharSequence text = dateTime.getTime();
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.WidgetUpdateTime, text);
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.progressWidget, View.GONE);
        remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.WidgetRefresh_btn, View.VISIBLE);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);
    }



    public static ArrayList<String> getRssItems(String feedUrl, int appWidgetId) 
    {

    }


    public static class UpdateService extends Service {
        @Override
        public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.WidgetRefresh_btn, View.GONE);
            remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.progressWidget, View.VISIBLE);


            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews);


        WidgetActivity.Widget.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            return null;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to understand what you mean by:

> When debugging I noticed that the first widget the widgetid of te second used for updating

But, I think I understand your general problem: your AppWidgets are not being updated correctly? After glancing at your code, it looks like your problem could be that appWidgetId is declared as static. Perhaps try removing that keyword.

Also, I don't see anywhere in your code a button.

EDIT

It looks like your appWidgetId is being overwritten. Here is my suggestion, take advantage of the AppWidgetProvider being a broadcast receiver and instead send a broadcast as a result of your PendingIntent button click. You will also have to make sure to pass the appWidgetId as an extra to ensure that the correct widget gets updated. Here is an example, should be in your updateAppWidget method:

```
Intent refreshAction = new Intent();
refreshAction.setAction(MY_CUSTOM_REFRESH_ACTION);
refreshAction.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
PendingIntent refreshPendingIntent.........
```

And then in the onReceive override:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  .....
  Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
  int appWidgetId = extras.getExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID);
  .....
}
```

And then you should be ready to go, updating the correct widget. One more caveat, make sure to read the documentation on BroadcastReceivers if you have not already. You will have to register to accept MY_CUSTOM_REFRESH_ACTION within the WidgetActivity element in your AndroidManifest.

Comment: I've try that, but without result. The R.id.WidgetRefresh_btn is the button. What I mean with the widgetsId's: The first widget updates with the ID of the seconde widget (in the update-methode). So I think the widgetID is overwritten.

Comment: Check my answer again, I have updated it to provide some code and what should be a solution.